# c# declaring a new variable every time a loop is run to count characters of a string

Tags: c#

I want to create a new variable everytime a loop is run, for example:

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <=  'z'; c++;) 
    {
        countA++;
        // I want to create a new variable(countB, countC, etc.) every time
        // the loop is run
        //if you couldn't tell already, this loop counts letters in a string
    }
```

Comment: You simply cannot declare a new variab at each loop. Shouldn't it be better to use an array for your purpose?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Paolo Costa, you could use an array:

```
string str = "lowercase string";
int[] counts = new int['z' - 'a' + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    char ch = str[i];

    if (ch < 'a' || ch > 'z')
    {
        continue;
    }

    counts[ch - 'a']++;
}
```

Note that in C# (and in .NET), `char`s are more similar to `int` than to `string`. They are a number (technically an [integral type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx)) that can have values between 0 and 65535, and that can be implicitly converted to `int`. Here I'm playing on it :-) `a` is 97 and `z` is 122. `'z' - 'a' + 1` is `122 - 97 + 1 == 26`, and that is the size of the array you need. `ch - 'a'` tranforms the characters between `a` and `z` in numbers between 0 and 26. This because clearly `'a' - 'a'` is 0, `'b' - 'a'` is 1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In order to count the characters you can use a single variable of `Dictionary` type as below.

Outside the loop

```
IDictionary<char, int> count = new Dictionary<char, int>();
```

Inside the loop increase the values as per the character which is found inside the loop.

```
...
...
count['a']++;
...
...
count['b']++;
```

Comment: Why not a dictionary of char, int?

Answer (score 0):

## I am guessing you wish to count small letter frequencies.

### You could use :

```
    int[] freq = new int[26]; // only 26 characters you are counting
    for(char c = 'a'; c<='z'; c++)
    {
        freq[c-97] = data.Count(x => x == c);  // data is a string of characters
    }
```

Comment: ASCII code for 'a' to 'z' is 97-122 so c-97 will give desired indices.
:)
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First I want to go through what's wrong with your code.

You have no `string` that you're iterating through, using the postfix increment operator on a `char` only helps you iterate through a range of characters, but your aim isn't to iterate through a-z, but each `char` of a `string`.

```
string text = "This  is a random string that I'll iterate through " +
              "to find out how many instances of a character it contains";

Dictionary<char, int> Counter = new Dictionary<char, int>();
foreach (char c in text)
{
    if (!Counter.ContainsKey(c))
    {
        Counter.Add(c, 0);
    }

    Counter[c] += 1;
}

foreach (var kv in Counter)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("The character {0} occured {1} times", kv.Key, kv.Value);
}
```

[image: Char count]